# How to mount a GCP Filestore instance over VPN on an AWS instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-filestore

I set up a Filestore server on GCP, and also built a VPN connection between GCP and AWS. I would like to mount over NFS the Filestore instance in GCP on an AWS instance.

I can successfully ping the internal IP addresses of corresponding VMs, but it times out when I ping the Filestore instance from an AWS VM.

One issue is that the CIDR block from GCP is on 10.10.0.0/16, while the Filestore instance sits on 10.8.79.89.

Is it possible to establish an NFS mount between the two platforms, and if so, what might be required to accomplish this?

As for setting up the VPN connection, I basically followed this tutorial to a tee: https://cloud.google.com/files/CloudVPNGuide-UsingCloudVPNwithAmazonWebServices.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: What type of VPN connection? Edit your question with details on the VPN and the route table in your Google VPC.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the comment. I included the guide that I followed for setting it up, which includes the details of the VPN and route table entries.